# CMW and NANDroid backup

Tags: backup

I found a CMW .img file another user used for same model, is that the right one or are there different CMW links?

If it is the right one, or you link a CMW download, the next step is
to write 
adb reboot bootloader
fastboot flash recovery cmw.img
fastboot reboot

How do I get the Nandroid backup after that?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

1. [clockworkmod-recovery](/questions/tagged/clockworkmod-recovery), [twrp](/questions/tagged/twrp) and other image files are always specific to a device (brand+model). So if the image you found was for the very same brand and model, it should fit. But keep in mind that some manufacturers have slightly different models going by the same name (e.g. Samsung often does that), so make sure it matches. For TWRP, you can check on officially supported devices [here](https://twrp.me/Devices/) (and also download the images from there)
2. The steps to install it are indeed to boot into [fastboot](/questions/tagged/fastboot) and flash the image. But as pre-condition, the [bootloader](/questions/tagged/bootloader) of the device must be unlocked (see: [bootloader-lock tag-wiki](/tags/bootloader-lock/info))
3. with the custom recovery (CWM or TWRP) successfully installed, boot to recovery. You'll find the backup menu there – that's the [nandroid](/questions/tagged/nandroid) backup.

Comment: Thank you. I tried it but the bootloader is locked. I didn't want to use the adb reboot oem-unlock command because it will include a factory reset and delete the data I want to backup. I unlocked it in the developer options and used the fastboot flashing unlock command but it said <bootloader>got key event 4
<bootloader>EV_POWER received
FAILED. <remote: couldn't change state!>. How do I unlock it?

Comment: Sorry, Rea – but usually the only way to unlock goes along with that implied factory-reset. In developer settings you only specify to *permit* unlocking, it doesn't unlock it automatically.